# Why does yarn install dev dependencies but I just need the builds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

If I use `yarn add <package-name>`, Yarn will install both dependencies and devDependencies of `<package-name>`.
Is it intended?

I checked the documentation but I couldn't find a way to prevent installing the development dependencies.
`devDependencies` are the dependencies that were used to compile the sources of one package, therefore if I am in a production environment I don't need them.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use `--production=true` (or simply `--production` or `--prod` for short). It is indeed normal behaviour; Yarn assumes you are in a 'development' context unless your NODE_ENV environment variable is set to 'production'.

Have a look at Yarn's [documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/).

Comment: This functionality seems to be broken due to https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6323

Comment: Not "broken" but "badly designed" `--prod` still downloads and "installs" `dev` packages IF yarn needs to resolve "full tree".   Just use `yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile` and matching `yarn.lock` and `--production` will work as expected.

Comment: @ddotsenko : that is so helpful, it is now an answer . Please write your own for your well-deserved credit and @ notify me for mine to be deleted.

Comment: `--production` flag has been deprecated for yarn 2.0. How to prevent yarn 2.0 from installing dev dependencies?

Comment: Late to the party but the new way to do this in Yarn 2+ is by using `yarn workspaces focus --production --all`: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/workspaces/focus

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an answer, but I'd like to note that none of the above is correct as of January 2022. Yarn will *always* install devDependencies regardless of options and NODE_ENV envvar.

Comment: I'm confused about this answer, which seems to be talking about `yarn install`, but the question is about `yarn add [pkg]`.

Obviously `yarn install` is going to install dev deps by default, but `yarn add` definitely shouldn't install dev deps of the added dependency.

Comment: if any yarn devs see this - please realize naming the command "yarn workspaces focus --production --all" makes no sense from the user's perspective.  We are installing packages and we only want to install those listed in dependencies.  Name your command something that makes sense.

Answer (score 15):

As said in [the comment by @ddotsenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530678/why-will-yarn-install-dev-dependencies-when-i-just-need-the-builds#comment110960282_49530813)

> Not "broken" but "badly designed" --prod still downloads and "installs" dev packages IF yarn needs to resolve "full tree". Just **use `yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile`** and matching yarn.lock and --production will work as expected.

That worked to remove a 210 MB node_modules to 70 MB, similar to `npm` and `pnpm`.

Answer (score 6):

`NODE_ENV=production` also prevent install devDependencies

Comment: use `NODE_ENV=production` as environments before excute `yarn` or `yarn install`

Answer (score 3):

With Yarn 2+, it seems that Yarn focuses on PnP installs, meaning a content-addressable data-structure that replaces classic `node_modules` and is assumed to be part of the package, hence package sources will automatically include  `devDependencies`.

Nevertheless, `yarn workspaces focus <name> --production` allows to install a workspace package *without* `devDependencies. See https://yarnpkg.com/cli/workspaces/focus for more information.

Comment: Please share your package.json, and share more information about your environment such as the package manager that you used yarn|npm|pnpm and what the versions and system information.

Answer (score 1):

Yarn has a --production option, which will cause it to install only production dependencies. This is shown [here](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-production-true-false)

Comment: bro this flag doesn't even work... that's the main issue

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers seem to miss the point of the question (including the accepted answer).

> If I invoke `yarn add <my-package>`, Yarn will install both dependencies and devDependencies of `<my-package>`. Is it normal behavior?

No, this sounds like a bug. I don't see this behaviour with the latest version of yarn v1.

If I `yarn add foo` to my project, I should then have installed:

- my direct dependencies
- `foo`
- any dependencies of `foo` and their dependencies recursively
- *not* devDependencies of `foo`
- devDependencies of my project (unless using various production flags/vars mentioned in other answers)
- (as far as I know, yarn doesn't automatically install peer dependencies as in recent npm versions)

If you are running `yarn add` it can be assumed you are in a "dev" context.