# How to install only "devDependencies" using yarn

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, package.json

I want to install only the "devDependencies" listed in the package.json file using yarn. I use the command `yarn install --production=false` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think Yarn has an only-dev option.

Comment: First commentout dependencies, but not devDependencies,  then run `yarn install`. after the installation then get back your package.json file as earlier

Comment: @arulmanivenkatesh that installs only the production dependencies and **not** the development dependencies, which is the opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: Why do you want only dev deps?

Comment: One reason could be wanting to run the tests isolated from whatever environment is used to build the actual app. But then it's worth considering separating the test dependencies into a separate repo (or sub repo in case of a mono repo)

Answer (score 5):

Yarn [doesn't support it currently](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3254#issuecomment-363485750) (2022, v1.22). Actually [neither does npm since v7](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2028). An argument against it is you most likely need the production deps to do development. For example, how you gonna test the build without the prod deps? Although seems plenty of people are asking for it - see above links.

The reverse (install only prod deps) is more common use case and is [supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49530813/2038383): `yarn install --prod`.

Comment: the reverse is supported only by the classic yarn v1. if you try this command with the latest yarn v3, you'll get "Unknown Syntax Error: Unsupported option name ("--prod")" error.